# How to compare NPVariant objects?

Tags: npapi

I am registering listeners from JS to NPAPI plugin. 
In order not to register same listener multiple times I need a way to compare passed NPVariant object to those already in the list.

This is how I'm registering listeners from JS :

```
    PluginObject.registerListener("event", listener);
```

and then in plugin source :

```
    for (l=head; l!=NULL; l=l->next) {
      // somehow compare the listeners
      // l->listener holds NPVariant object
      if (l->listener-> ??? == new_lle->listener-> ???) 
      {
        found = 1;
        DBG("listener is a duplicate, not adding.");
        NPN_MemFree(new_lle->listener);
        free(new_lle);
        break;
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're talking about a javascript function the NPVariant is just an NPObject.

```
typedef struct _NPVariant {
  NPVariantType type;
  union {
    bool boolValue;
    int32_t intValue;
    double_t doubleValue;
    NPString stringValue;
    NPObject *objectValue;
  } value;
} NPVariant;
```

compare the val.type and val.objectValue. This will usually work, but if it doesn't there isn't another way so you're still better off trying it.  I guess one other possibility would be to create a javascript function to compare them, inject it with NPN_Evaluate and call it with the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rely on objectValue. For instance if you do the following:

`foo={};
bar=foo;
x={};

x.f=foo; x.b=bar;`

Now, if you call `NPN_Enumerate` and pass x as the NPObject, you get two identifiers. Calling GetProperty for each of these returns NPVariants, but the value of `variant->value.objectValue` will be different for each, and different again in subsequent calls to `NPN_Enumerate`.

taxilian: is there significant overhead in calling `NPN_Invoke` with the two NPObjects, just to test for equality? This also involves some calls to `GetProperty` and the creation of identifiers and calling the NPVARIANT macros to test the results, etc.. I am wondering just how much logic I should be injecting and evaluating in Javascript.. this code injection seems to come up as a solution again and again. Is it costly?